# RESTKIT response only first KVC in mapping result dictionary or array

Tags: ios, arrays, restkit, response, partial

I'm receiving a dictionary from my `restkit` request as respond but only one of values are included. I am missing bunch of KV from my JSON.

JSON response from API:

```
{"categories" : [
{
  "status" : 1,
  "rest_id" : 1,
  "id" : 1,
  "title" : "01. BasicC",
  "description" : "basic description"
},
{
  "status" : 1,
  "rest_id" : 1,
  "id" : 26,
  "title" : "01. Deli",
  "description" : "deli description"
}
]}
```

IOS Function to request:

```
- (void)loadProduct{
_categoriesDic=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
RKObjectMapping* productMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ProductCategory     class]];
[productMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                 @"id": @"id",
                                                 @"rest_id": @"rest_id",
                                                 @"title": @"title",
                                                 @"description": @"description",
                                                 @"status":@"status"
                                                 }];
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:productMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"categories" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] init];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=1"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/REST/v2/productCategories"];
NSData *json_data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: json_data];

RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];
[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Categories: %@", mappingResult.dictionary);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
}];
[objectRequestOperation start];
}
```

response:

```
Load collection of Categories: {
categories =     (
    "basic description",
    "deli description"
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your code does some slightly odd things (like create an empty immutable dictionary, and POST to an endpoint which should be using a GET) it does appear to work. It looks like you just aren't fully understanding the response, and that's because you are inadvertently overriding a built in method.

The log you show contains:

```
{
    categories =     (
        "basic description",
        "deli description"
    );
}
```

is the `description` of a dictionary which contains 1 key (categories), which is an array of 2 objects. Now, those 2 objects have their `description` method called as well in order to generate the log contents. Unfortunately, you have a property called `description` so that is accessed instead of the superclass implementation., and hence you just get the descriptions.

Now, that doesn't mean the mapping hasn't worked, just that the log is misleading.

You should change the `description` on your destination object to another name, like `overview` and then your log will be meaningful (and you won't see similar issues in future).

Comment: Thnx a lot Wain,
this helped me really,
so U are saying I should do GET instead of POST to retrieve data from my API ?
I thought that might be a good idea to have parameters set at the post body instead of using parameters ?= in the url,

Do you happen to have a good example for my case ?
Thnx again,

Comment: I'm saying that when you're calling `.../v2/productCategories` I'd expect you to be doing a GET to collect data and a POST to update an existing product category. Indeed I'd expect the endpoint to be `.../v2/productCategory`. It doesn't have to be like this, it's just a question of how RESTful and close to the 'spec' you're trying to be. You might be interested in http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html